# How to use a variable inside another variable with <%= render ... %> in EEx

Tags: phoenix-framework

I would like to use `<%= @slider_id %>` (which is defined when calling `<%= render ... %>` for another - similar - template) inside this snippet:

```
<%= render My_project.ComponentView, "video.html",
            video_class: "slider secondLayer<%= @slider_id %> three",
            video_id: nil,
            video_effect: "background"
 %>
```

but I'm getting an error.
Is there a way of doing this in the template only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already in an Elixir block, you can just interpolate the variable:

```
video_class: "slider secondLayer#{@slider_id} three",
```